# Ajax form select changes doesn't appear in jQuery .serialize/.val

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm retrieving form with .load jQuery function and places it in document body.

After that I'm changing select value (manually) and trying to save form with ajax .post request.

Select value retrieved by jQuery in any way (with .val or sereilize) doesn't changes. Value stays as it was rendered.

Without **prevetnDefault** (with plain POST request) form saves as expected. But both .val on select or .sereilize on form returns old select value (not really selected).

```
<form
       id="phrase-fake-form-12243"
       method="POST"
       action="/phrase-fake/change-group/12243/3">

            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='UQuHH3ahAnBaSUPsCBaF1QKF4I0O48AO' />
            <select name="group" id="phrase-fake-modal-group-dropdown">

                    <option value="20393"
                            selected="selected">
                        1
                    </option>

                    <option value="20405"
                            >
                        2
                    </option>

                    <option value="20417"
                            >
                        3
                    </option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="ui button blue">
        </form>
```

JS:

```
<script>

$("#phrase-fake-form-12243").submit(function (event) {

    console.log($('#phrase-fake-form-12243').serialize())
    console.log($('#phrase-fake-modal-group-dropdown').dropdown('get value'))
    $.post('/phrase-fake/change-group/12243/3', $('#phrase-fake-form-12243').serialize())

    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Actually it's seems like a bug..

Comment: And what's `.dropdown()`, you're using some sort of plugin here

Comment: It seemed that jQuery of old versions do not support `serialize()` for select elements

Comment: If that is your case, upgrade your jQuery

Comment: jquery - 2.1.4, is it old?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library, [form2js](https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js)

You just have to call the method `.toObject()` on the jQuery object.
For example, if this is your html

```
<form id="test">
...
</form>
```

You can get the all the form element values by

```
var formObject = $("#test").toObject();
```